# Time complexity of Jacobi sums

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, finite-fields, computational-complexity, exponential-sum

How would one go about computing the time complexity of a Jacobi sum, such as $$J_5(\chi,\chi)=\sum_{s=0}^{p-1}\chi(s)\chi(1-s),$$ where $\chi$ is a character of $\mathbb{F}_p$ mapping a fixed non-quintic element in $\mathbb{F}_p$ to $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/5}$ and $p$ is a prime congruent to 1 mod 5?

In particular, if we were to write $$J_5(\chi,\chi)=c_0+c_1\zeta+c_2\zeta^2+c_3\zeta^3+c_4\zeta^4,$$

what would be the big-O for finding the $c_i$?

Comment: so you meant $5 | p-1$ ? since characters modulo a prime $p$  are of the form $\chi(n) = e^{2i  \pi a L(n) / (p-1)}$ with $L(n)$ a discrete logarithm modulo $p$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; I'll edit the question.

Comment: and you except a better algorithm than finding a generator and then $L(n)$ and $\chi(n)$ by exponentiation ?

Comment: Perhaps not, but what would be the time complexity of what you propose?

Comment: Are you implying that $\chi$ is of order five? I somehow suspect that your description does not imply  that. But the formula at the end suggests that this is what you had in mind.

Comment: No, $\chi$ doesn't have to be of order five -- I've edited the question.

Comment: @whetham what I said since the beginning is that $J_5(\chi,\chi)=c_0+c_1\zeta+c_2\zeta^2+c_3\zeta^3+c_4\zeta^4, c_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ means $p \equiv 1 \bmod 5$ and$\chi(n)^5 = |\chi(n)| = 1_{gcd(n,p) = 1}$. And did you try the basic algorithm I described ?